# SQL Loader fails when opening control file

Tags: java, oracle10g, sql-loader

Well this is a very strange behavior.

When I execute the command

`sqlldr userid=usuario/prueba@basedatos control './controlFiles/MyArchivo  2011.csv` (notice that there are two whitespaces between MyArchivo and 2011) the loader fails and sends this error:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Lun Abr 30 18:02:27 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (./controlFiles/MyArchivo 2011.ctl)
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

I made some experiments and this just happens when there are **two** (or more) consecutive whitespaces in the filename, can anyone explain to me what's going on?

Does this has to do with the OS? with SQLLdr?

Comment: Someone? Any idea? I've been trying to keep those consecutive spaces but I wasn't able to. Could it be a java bug?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use filename without any spaces in the name and also in the path?